# How can I test a normal plain javascript file?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing

If I have a plain javascript file

```
// hello.js
function hello(string) {
  return 'hello ' + string;
}
```

How can I use unit test over the functions in this file?

### EDIT

Currently I have two ideas (both using nodejs):

#### eval + mochajs/nodejs

Test with mochajs test framework, for this I need use `eval`

```
// test file
var assert = require('assert');
var fs = require('fs');
eval.apply(this, [fs.readFileSync('./hello.js').toString()]);

describe('hello function', function() {
  it('test output', function () {
    assert.equal('hello world', hello('world'));
  });
});
```

#### automatically pre-convert the javascript file in a nodejs module

Before to run the test create automatically a copy of `hello.js` with the structure of a nodejs module and run the test over the copy

```
// _hello.js to testing
exports.hello = function(string) {
  return 'hello ' + string;
}

// test file
var assert = require('assert');
var hello = require('./_hello.js');

describe('hello function', function() {
  it('test output', function () {
    assert.equal('hello world', hello.hello('world'));
  });
});
```

In the second option, I need to make a script to convert the javascript file into a nodejs module, but I get some things like, in a nodejs module I can get the coverage measure.

Comment: define unit test. A unit test is a concept, not part of JavaScript

Comment: How can I test the functions in the file?

Comment: @JuanPablo: By writing code which invokes the function and examines the result.

Comment: @David yes, but how can I invokes a plain javascript file to examine the result?

Comment: Look into tape (https://github.com/substack/tape). There's a good write up here: https://ponyfoo.com/articles/testing-javascript-modules-with-tape.

Comment: F12 and find your file in Sources keep breakpoints and test it. And you to  invoke include the js file and call hello function with the parameter needed.

Comment: @JuanPablo Any reason why you want to use unit test and nodejs? that seems like a lot of work to me, when browser tools can do those anyway

Comment: @Kimbi My first option is nodejs beause I need run the test in command line without GUI, I can't use something like chrome or firefox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I solved with karma + phantomjs + jasmine

with karma I can load the javacript file and tests files adding lines to the karma configuration file this way

```
// karma.conf.js
files: [
  'hello.js',
  'hello_test.js'
],
```

and write the tests this way

```
// test_hello.js
describe('test lib', function () {
  it('test hello', function () {
    expect(hello('world')).toBe('hello world');
  });
});
```

A example available in github

https://github.com/juanpabloaj/karma_phantomjs_jasmine

Answer (score 5):

For this you could use [QUnit](https://qunitjs.com/).

You would setup a test harness like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Test Suite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.10.1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="qunit"></div>
    <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.10.1.js"></script>
    <script src="hello.js"></script>
    <script>
        // This can of course be in a separate file
        QUnit.test( "hello test", function( assert ) {
          assert.ok( hello('world') === "hello world", "Passed!" );
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Love the simplicity of testing everything in the browser without packet manager. Definitely that was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [PreemJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preem), it's good for API\Unit javascript testing

```
    "use strict";

    let Preem = require('preem');

    let preem = new Preem();

    preem.testModule("Test hello function", function(beforeEach, checkIf) {

        function hello(string) {
           return 'hello ' + string;
        }

        let str = hello('world');

        checkIf(str).isEqualTo('hello world', "strings are equal", "strings aren't equal");

    }
    preem.start();
```

Answer (score -4):

1) go to https://jsfiddle.net/,
2) type in your code in Javascript block.
3) Open Chrome Console window by press F12 on Windows.
4) Click Run on left-top.
hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: alternatively right click and use "inspect", then open the "console" tap if it is not automatically pick it as default landing screen.